# Dynamic field type in DTO

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, jackson

I am using `Spring-MVC` and I have a DTO structured like below to receive `JSON` data from client (a `foo` entity) to save it into the database with `JPA`  :

```
public class FooDTO {

    public Integer id;
    public String label;
    public Double amount;
    public List<Integer> states;
    ...
```

But when the client want to edit the `foo` entity i have to structure it like below

```
public class FooDTO {

    public Integer id;
    public String label;
    public Double amount;
    public List<SimpleDto> states;
    ...
```

With `SimpleDto`

```
public class SimpleDto {
    public Integer value;
    public String label;
}
```

The difference is just the `states` type it is sometimes `List<SimpleDto>` and sometimes `List<Integer>` And i do not want to create another dto.

So how can i implement dynamic field type in my dto (json) ?

P.S JSON data is handled by `com.fasterxml.jackson.core`

Comment: I dont get it. just make it an `Object` and use a simple `instance of`, why is this so complicated?

Comment: @Eugene yeah `instance of` for primitive types but for my `SimpleDto` i think i have to use @ManojRamanan or not ?

Comment: do you know what `instanceOf` does? you said you have `SimpleDto` vs `Integer`. I also don't understand why you would not create another DTO, it's not that complicated.

Comment: @Eugene i dont want to repeat myself cause my DTO has many shared attribute.

Comment: well in such a case make a common class that has the shared fields and two new classes that extend that one.

Comment: point is that this is solveable in better ways most probably, not even the need for that `instanceof` check. If we knew _all_ the details of the problem, we could help, in a better way

Answer (score 8):

Using a custom deserializer is one way of solving your problem

```
    public class DynamicDeserializer extends JsonDeserializer {
    @Override
    public Object deserialize(JsonParser jp, DeserializationContext ctxt) throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
        String requestString = jp.readValueAsTree().toString();
        JSONArray jo = new JSONArray(requestString);
        List<SimpleDto> simpleDtoList = new ArrayList<>();
        List<Integer> integers = new ArrayList<>();
        if(jo!=null && jo.length()>0) {
            for (int i = 0; i < jo.length(); i++) {
                Object string = jo.get(0);
                if(string!=null && string instanceof JSONObject){
                    JSONObject value = jo.getJSONObject(i);
                    SimpleDto simpleDto = new SimpleDto();
                    simpleDto.setValue(value.getInt("value"));
                    simpleDtoList.add(simpleDto);
                }else{
                    integers.add(jo.getInt(0));
                }
            }
        }


        return integers.isEmpty() ? simpleDtoList:integers;
    }
}
```

The controller where request is sent and printed back

```
@PostMapping("/test")
    public Optional<TestObject> testDynamicMapper(
            @RequestBody final TestObject testObject) {
        List<Object> states = testObject.getStates();

        for (Object object:states) {
            if(object instanceof SimpleDto){
                SimpleDto dto = (SimpleDto)object;
                System.out.println(dto.getValue());
            }
            if(object instanceof Integer){
                Integer dto = (Integer)object;
                System.out.println(dto);
            }
        }


        return Optional.of(testObject);
    }
```

The pojo class where there is an generic mapping

```
public class TestObject implements Serializable {

    @JsonDeserialize(using = DynamicDeserializer.class)
    private List<Object> states;


    public List<Object> getStates() {
        return states;
    }

    public void setStates(List<Object> states) {
        this.states = states;
    }


}
```

### Input payload for list of objects

```
{
  "states": [
    {
      "label": "1",
      "value": 0
    }
  ]
}
```

### Input payload for list of Integers

```
{
  "states": [
      1,2
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to use different classes: FooInfoDTO, FooDetailsDTO. It's usually used when you have master-details forms. In master(table) you show short info about objects (one DTO) and then navigating to details you fetch full object data (another DTO)

Comment: I do not want to use extra DTO

Answer (score 1):

Write a dto

```
public class FooDTO {

    public Integer id;
    public String label;
    public Double amount;
    public List<Object> states;
}
```

Typecast your DTO in Service class and handle the exception

Answer (score 0):

Use a Spring Type Converter for your DTO type.  That way the client can post a stateId and the Converter will resolve the correct DTO type for the given ID.

Here's an example:  https://www.baeldung.com/spring-type-conversions

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest not to add another DTO which promotes duplicates.
However you still need to add another DTO which will be dedicated to your respective service. You simply define the DTO using hierarchy.

```
public class FooDTO {

    public Integer id;
    public String label;
    public Double amount;
}
```

Define your response DTO to provide details by extending the generic details DTO i.e. FooDTO as follows,

```
public class FooDetailsOutDTO extends FooDTO {

    public List<Integer> states;

}
```

For edit you define DTO as follows,

```
public class FooUpdateDetailsInDTO extends FooDTO {

     public List<SimpleDto> states;

}
```

Comment: I do not want to use extra DTO

Answer (score 0):

You can use [JsonCreator](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.9/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonCreator.html) annotation and two constructors for item `POJO`. In case there is a primitive in array `1-arg` constructor will be used. In case of fully set object `2-arg` constructor will be used. See below example:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonCreator;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonCreator.Mode;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import java.util.List;

public class JsonApp {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        String json = "{\"id\":1,\"label\":\"LABEL\",\"amount\":1.23,\"states\":[1,{\"value\":2},{\"value\":3,\"label\":\"LAB\"}]}";
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

        Foo foo = mapper.readValue(json, Foo.class);
        System.out.println(foo);
    }
}

class Foo {

    private Integer id;
    private String label;
    private Double amount;
    private List<State> states;

    // getters, setters, toString
}

class State {

    private Integer value;
    private String label;

    @JsonCreator(mode = Mode.DELEGATING)
    public State(@JsonProperty("value") Integer value) {
        this(value, null);
    }

    @JsonCreator
    public State(@JsonProperty("value") Integer value, @JsonProperty("label") String label) {
        this.value = value;
        this.label = label;
    }

    // getters, setters, toString
}
```

Above code prints:

```
Foo{id=1, label='LABEL', amount=1.23, states=[State{value=1, label='null'}, State{value=2, label='null'}, State{value=3, label='LAB'}]}
```

Used version: [2.9.8](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-core/2.9.8)

Comment: I do not want to use empty label (null)

Comment: @Youssef, this is just `toString` method implementation which shows these objects in this way. Label property is set to `null` not to `"null"` `String`. Please, try my solution and you will see.

Comment: I know it work and i try it before i post this question ... but i am looking f a better solution with a real dynamic field type

Comment: @Youssef, What do you mean by `real dynamic field type`? How you would like to distinguish between list of `Integer`s and `DTO`? You can create `List<Object>` and once you will receive `Integer` and for object it will be `Map`. It is not possible to map it dynamically for `Integer` or `DTO`. You need to write custom deserialiser for this field. My solution gives you the same type in both cases, and you can even mix primitives with `DTO`.

Answer (score 0):

Another re-modelling approach:

```
 public class FooDTO {

    public Integer id;
    public String label;
    public Double amount;
    //not null!
    public List<Integer> states;
    //nullable!!
    ... List<String> stateLabels;
   // you should ensure "stable/consistent index/ordering" (relative to states)
   ...
```

...and accordingly use this for  "get" (individually accessing the labels) and for "post" (omitting labels;)

‐------------------------‐----

and even better:

```
   Map<Integer, String> states; // !?
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just add a getter which return Integer in `SimpleDto`

Add a getter which return `List<Integer>` in `FooDTO` using simple java Stream which map to Integer using the DTO getter

```
states.stream().map(SimpleDto::getValue).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to redesign the architecture entirely. Split main entity with a related collection(s).

Provide independent service to add/remove/set statuses per your entity. By this way, you can easily provide REST services to your client, which will be clear for usage.

Here is a set of possible methods, implemented via REST interface:

```
@Path(../foo)
@Produces
public interface FooService {
  //CRUD methods on Foo itself which work with attributes of Foo only
  ...
  @GET
  @Path("/{fooId}")
  FooDTO findById(@PathParam("fooId") int fooId);

  //status-related methods:
  @GET
  @Path("/{fooId}/status")
  List<SimpleDto> statuses(@PathParam("fooId") int fooId);

  @Post
  @Path("/{fooId}/status")
  void addStatus(@PathParam("fooId") int fooId, int statusId);

  @DELETE
  @Path("{fooId}/status")
  void deleteStatus(@PathParam("fooId") int fooId, int statusId);

  @PUT
  @Path("/status")
  void setStatuses(@PathParam("fooId") int fooId, List<Integer> newStatuses);
}
```

With this solution also there are some alternative options, I would prefer to return:

```
  @GET
  @Path("/{fooId}/status")
  List<Integer> statuses(@PathParam("fooId") int fooId);
```

Instead of list of DTO. And then would provide a service to get all statuses with their names without connection to Foo:

```
public interface StatusService {
  List<SimpleDto> statuses();
}
```

To simplify GUI components implementation, you can create Rest service that will return a combined data, like in your 2nd FooDto version. It also will reduce amount of rest calls. But having separate methods to work directly with a collection of items, will help a lot.

Answer (score -2):

you can use `generics`, change `List<Integer> states` to `List<?> states`